# My SQL query pulls inaccurate information about variable woocommerce products, but works fine for regular products. Why?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a rather long and complicated sql query that I use to pull product reports from Woocommerce (because the browser reports do not contain enough information for my superiors' liking)  For the most part, it works wonderfully.  But it gives me incorrect/unreliable data for variable products, and I am not sure why this is.

Query follows:

```
SELECT p.ID, b.meta_value, p.post_title, pv.meta_value, SUM( qty.meta_value ), var.meta_value, "CR [4/3]", SUM( tot.meta_value ), "Avg Prc [6/4] 3?", pr.meta_value, AVG(aic.meta_value) , "Grs Prft [(8-9)/8]", "GrAvPrft [(7-9)/7]", "Grs Markup [(8-9)/8]"

FROM wp_posts p INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta pid ON p.ID = pid.meta_value AND pid.meta_key = '_product_id'
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta qty ON pid.order_item_id = qty.order_item_id AND qty.meta_key = '_qty'
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta tot ON tot.order_item_id = qty.order_item_id AND tot.meta_key = '_line_total'
LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta var ON var.order_item_id = qty.order_item_id AND var.meta_key = '_variation_id'
LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta shp ON shp.order_item_id = qty.order_item_id AND shp.meta_key = '_per_product_shipping_cost'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pr ON pr.post_id = p.ID AND pr.meta_key = '_price'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON b.post_id = p.ID and b.meta_key = '_bucket'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pv ON p.ID = pv.post_id and pv.meta_key = '_page_views'
LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta aic ON aic.order_item_id = pid.order_item_id and aic.meta_key='_actual_item_cost'

INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oim ON oim.order_item_id = pid.order_item_id
INNER JOIN wp_posts ord ON oim.order_id = ord.ID


WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
AND oim.order_item_type = 'line_item'
AND tot.meta_value > 0
AND ord.post_status IN ('wc-completed', 'wc-processing')

GROUP BY p.ID;
```

Some of the stuff in the select statement is just placeholders for post-query calculations, just ignore those.  My main issue is that SUM( qty.meta_value ) and SUM( tot.meta_value ) give incorrect data for variable products.

Comment: :o you are trying to rape wordpress !!!